# Non-existent oh_my_zsh causing issues

Tags: macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I seem to not be able to get away from oh_my_zsh, which is causing errors.

- When I run `npm install`,  I am getting the error: `zsh: command
  not found: npm`.
- When I check which version of node I am running, I get `zsh: command
  not found: node`. Node is definitely installed.
- I tried uninstalling oh_my_zsh using `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` and
  trying `npm install` again. I again get the error `zsh: command not found: npm`.
- I tried uninstalling oh_my_zsh with Homebrew. I got the error `zsh: command not
  found: brew`.
- I tried restarting Terminal, and visually verified oh_my_zsh is not installed. I still get these errors.
- I tried reinstalling oh_my_zsh, using `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`. Still get `zsh: command not found: node`

I don't have a problem with oh_my_zsh (or homebrew); I actually like it. I used to have a work around. I have not installed anything recently.

eta: In addition to this, I've tried updating homebrew, thinking that there was some issue with Homebrew. But ultimately error when I using Homebrew is

`Error: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config not present or broken. Please reinstall pkg-config.`

Apparently Homebrew was able to update `Auto-updated Homebrew!` and then started to clean up packages and started to upgrade node.

I got the following `Caveats` and then the error.

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
 macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
  LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib
  CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/60.2: 249 files, 68.2MB, built in 6 minutes 47 seconds
==> Installing node
Error: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config not present or broken
Please reinstall pkg-config. Sorry :(
```

Comment: Please mention which OS and version you are using, also for ref: https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup

Comment: I'd suggest you start by turning on logging. `set -x` is your friend, especially with a PS4 that logs source file and line number.

Comment: BTW, if you have a solution, don't edit that into the question -- use the "add an answer" button. Your question shows up as unanswered until both (1) someone adds an answer (and that someone is allowed to be you!), and (2) you accept that answer (note that there's a delay before a self-answer can be accepted).

Comment: (It's also preferable for edits to a question to preserve narrative flow. Edit history is visible to everyone, so there's no obligation to write any notices regarding what was edited when or structure the text for clarity around same -- it's more important to make a question or answer read as cleanly and understandably as possible).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Apparently node wasn't installed or not installed correctly. I used the package installer from nodejs.org, not the Homebrew installation, to install node. `npm install`, `node -v` work as they should. I do get warnings when I run `brew doctor`, including mentions of node headers, but I will ignore them until something stops working again.